# calculating the average of last values in PHP using Queue

Tags: php, queue

My problem is easy to understand, I need to loop a table and calculate the average of every last 4 value. I try to use Queue to Push the current value and to pop the first value pushed.

I have 2 problem, The Queus works as Stack, when I pop, the last value goes out and not the first one

```
$q = new SplQueue();
$q->push(1);
$q->push(2);
$q->push(3);
$q->push(4);
$q->push(5);
$q->pop();
```

I get this  Array as `( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 ) )`

I want this  Array as `( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 ) )`

Second problem, How to use `array_sum($q) / $counter[$q];` on Queue ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As it is said in documentation (http://php.net/manual/ro/class.splqueue.php ), if you use `push()` and `pop()` it will behave like a stack. Use `enqueue()` and `dequeue()`

If you want to get the average of last 4 values, you can create a new array containing the 4 values of your queue `dequeue()`, then use `array_sum($a)/ count($a)` on it

If you do not want to create a new array you can simply:

```
$sum = 0;
$lastElements = 4;
for($i = 0;$i<$lastElements;$i++)
   $sum+= $q.dequeue()
echo $sum/$lastElements;
```

And you can scale this by changing the $lastElements value.The code is not tested